# Тире или запятая в сложноподчиненных предложениях, начинающихся с "если"?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

"Если у вас нету дома....пожары ему не страшны" или "Если не хватает денег... работайте побольше" или "Если не получается похудеть...приходите в нам". 
Какой знак препинания нужен в таких предложениях? Это одно правило или в каждом случае как-то по-разному ставится знак препинания (где-то - запятая, а где-то - тире)? 
Авторскую пунктуацию не рассматриваю, там всё понятно)

Comment: И еще интересует конкретное правило. Допустим, у Розенталя параграф 111. Это я к примеру)

Answer (score 1):

Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; **если же придаточная часть стоит перед главной частью или после нее, то отделяется от нее запятой:**

> Если я мешаю, то уйду (Пауст.); Когда стемнело, я зажег лампу (Пришв.);

В сложноподчиненном предложении может ставиться тире:

1) после придаточной части, стоящей перед главной частью (особенно при наличии слов это, вот, то в главной части): Когда тоска — хорошо писать (Пауст.); Что в воздухе хлябь — на то уже не обращалось внимания (Ч.); Когда это кричит орел, сокол, ястреб, наконец, — это и красиво и мощно (М. Г.);

2) при усилении вопросительного характера предложения для подчеркивания необычности расположения придаточной части перед главной: А что такое влияние — ты знаешь? (Зерн.); Зачем всё это у вас произошло — скажи мне (обычное расположение изъяснительной придаточной части — после главной части);

3) при наличии нескольких придаточных частей для подчеркивания обобщающего характера главной части: Где я буду этот учебный год, переведусь ли куда — ведь обо всём этом надо думать! (Зерн.);

> См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской  орфографии и пунктуации.